# Sum of weighted cosine functions

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, trigonometric-series

I have got a question and I would appreciate if one could help!
I want to maximize a function that after some algebraic manipulation results in the sum of weighted cosine with different phases.

Assume $\theta_i$ and $b_i$ are known values. I want to calculate $\phi_i$ values so that the following function is maximized:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\cos(\phi_i +  \theta_i)$$

Is there any standard way to solve the problem?

any hint/help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set $ \phi_i = - \theta_i $ if $ b_i \ge 0 $ or $ \phi_i = \pi - \theta_i $ otherwise.

That will make sure every term is maximized.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. however, I realized that I have been careless in formulating my problem. I have posted a new question in [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660186/sum-of-weighted-cosine-functions-2)

Answer (score 1):

If $b_i$ is positive:
$$
\max\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n b_i\cos(\phi_i+\theta_i)\right\}=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \max\left\{\cos(\phi_i+\theta_i)\right\}=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i,
$$
as the $\cos$ function cannot exceed 1. This maximum is reached for
$$
\phi_i=2k\pi-\theta_i, \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
If $b_i$ is negative, with a similar argument:
$$
\phi_i=\pi+2k\pi-\theta_i, \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. however, I realized that I have been careless in formulating my problem. I have posted a new question in [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660186/sum-of-weighted-cosine-functions-2)